# Is map function on Datasets optimized for operations on one column?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

For `DataFrame`, it is easy to generate a new column with some operation using a `udf` with `df.withColumn("newCol", myUDF("someCol"))`. To do something like this in `Dataset`, I guess I would be using the `map` function:

```
def map[U](func: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
```

You have to pass the entire case class `T` as input to the function. If the `Dataset[T]` has a lot of fields/columns, it would seem very inefficient to be passing the entire row if you just wanted to make one extra column by operating on one of the many columns of `T`. My question is, is Catalyst smart enough to be able to optimize this?

Answer (score 3):

> Is Catalyst smart enough to be able to optimize this?

**tl;dr** No. See [SPARK-14083 Analyze JVM bytecode and turn closures into Catalyst expressions](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14083).

There's currently no way Spark SQL's Catalyst Optimizer know what you do in your Scala code.

Quoting [SPARK-14083](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14083):

> One big advantage of the Dataset API is the type safety, at the cost of performance due to heavy reliance on user-defined closures/lambdas. These closures are typically slower than expressions because we have more flexibility to optimize expressions (known data types, no virtual function calls, etc). In many cases, it's actually not going to be very difficult to look into the byte code of these closures and figure out what they are trying to do. If we can understand them, then we can turn them directly into Catalyst expressions for more optimized executions.

And there's even your case mentioned:

> `df.map(_.name)`  // equivalent to expression `col("name")`

As you can see it's still open and I doubt anyone works on this currently.

---

What you could do to help Spark Optimizer is to `select` that one column and only then use `map` operator with a one-argument UDF.

That would certainly match your requirements of not passing the entire JVM object to your function, but would not get rid of this slow deserialization from an internal row representation to your Scala object (that would land on the JVM and occupy some space until a GC happens).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure myself since I could not find a response anywhere.

Let's have a dataset which contains case classes with multiple fields:

```
scala> case class A(x: Int, y: Int)
scala> val dfA = spark.createDataset[A](Seq(A(1, 2)))
scala> val dfX = dfA.map(_.x)
```

Now if we check the optimized plan we get the following:

```
scala> val plan = dfX.queryExecution.optimizedPlan

SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, true] AS value#8]
    +- MapElements <function1>, obj#7: int
        +- DeserializeToObject newInstance(class A), obj#6: A
           +- LocalRelation [x#2, y#3]
```

According to the more verbose `plan.toJSON` the `DeserializeToObject` step assumes both `x` and `y` to be present.

As you proof take for example the following snippet which uses reflection instead of directly touching the fields of `A` which still works.

```
val dfX = dfA.map(
  _.getClass.getMethods.find(_.getName == "x").get.invoke(x).asInstanceOf[Int]
)
```